# Текст разбить на массив из слов

Tags: c#

Нужно текст разбить на массив из слов - подобное делается c помощью Split ?

А как разбить допустим не только если `" "`, но и по всяких символам типа `!?,.` и т.д.

Comment: [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `String.Split()`.

```
string value =  "fi,rst@se?co!nd.com";
string[] separators = {"@", ".", "?", "!", ","};
string[] words = value.Split(separators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```